# create a thumbnail from video hosted on different server in php

Tags: php, video, video-thumbnails

is it possible to create a thumbnail of video that is hosted on different site? I can use ffmpeg but i think you can use it to create thumbnail only if the video is on your directory?

If possible I don't want to download the video cause it will use lot of time and process for my server.

Im using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Many sites, such as YouTube, will use the `media` tag for allowing media data to be displayed in feeds:

```
<media:thumbnail url='http://img.youtube.com/vi/8aYQ_wjmriQ/2.jpg' height='90' width='120' time='00:01:23' yt:name='default'>
```

You will need to search the source page you are referencing for such a tag.